# Java equivalent to python's json.dumps

Tags: java, python, json

Python code:

```
import json
jsonvalue = json.dumps({"key":key_string,"value":unsafe_string})

cursor_mysql.execute("""UPDATE data SET json = %s WHERE id = %s""", (jsonvalue, somerowid))
```

`jsonvalue` is a valid json produced by `json.dumps` even if unsafe_string contains unicodes. Is there a similar function in Java?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/338586/a-better-java-json-library

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need [json-simple](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple) or [Google's gson](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md#object-examples)

[Encoding using json-simple](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/EncodingExamples):

```
  JSONObject obj=new JSONObject();
  obj.put("name","foo");
  obj.put("num",new Integer(100));
  obj.put("balance",new Double(1000.21));
  obj.put("is_vip",new Boolean(true));
  obj.put("nickname",null);
  System.out.print(obj);


Result: {"balance":1000.21,"num":100,"nickname":null,"is_vip":true,"name":"foo"}
```

Similarly [Decoding](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/DecodingExamples).

Comment: This does not place spaces after the colons.  Is there a library that will product the exact same output as Python's json.dumps?  json.dumps({'foo':'bar'}) = '{"foo": "bar"}'

Comment: This is not quite the same thing.  json.dumps() produces a string, whereas JSONObject() produces an object.

Comment: @MelissaGuo JSONObject's `toString()` returns a well formatted json string.

Comment: @Stimp Did you find a solution to match python '{"foo": "bar"}' to java {'foo':'bar'}

Comment: @Stimp, I was able to do it but not along with indentation.
Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61952317/after-a-customprettyprinter-in-jackson-indentation-settings-are-not-working

Answer (score 4):

Using [Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes):

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.writeValue(dst, obj); // where 'dst' can be File, OutputStream or Writer
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [flexjson](http://flexjson.sourceforge.net/):

```
String json = new flexjson.JSONSerializer().serialize(obj);
```